# MVC control databinding with nosql database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, calendar, nosql, ravendb

I have a MVC application that I am building with RavenDB as the main database

In my application, I need a calendar control that needs to be strongly data binded (with RavenDB data)I need calendar control to post data to raven, show dates from ravendb on a calendar control (two way data flow) etc..

Any one have any suggestions for me.. probably some one who did this sort of thing using ravendb, mvc and a calendar control.

What calendar control out there best suits my needs here.. a Jquery date picker? Telerik MVC Calendar ? or any other?

Any input, comments, help is appreciated.

Comment: jquery datepicker it client side and it open source you do not want to limit yourself to third party plugins

Comment: *someone who bound RavenDB data to a calendar control in MVC*.  I imagine that group of people is pretty small.

Comment: @user1258393 did my answer below help you at all?

Answer (score 3):

Well RavenDB allows you to deserialize into a regular POCO class, so given a class like this:

```
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }   
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```

You can then just load a doc like so:

```
session.Load<User>("users/1");
```

From that point onwards you can use the object however you want. You can bind against it, pass it into the view, add attributes to it, etc.